# given time get rows within 5min range in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes.

What I want to do is looping through each row in df_1 get its time, user_id then get rows that match user_id and time +- 5mins and get first row's data. If not within 5 mins return NaN

**note:** that there can be multiple user_id for both dataframe

df_1 looks something like:

```
user_id      created_time       
   1          2020-03-01 00:00:25
   2          2020-03-06 04:20:25
   3          2020-03-06 07:00:15
```

df_2:

```
user_id          updated_at           lat        lng
  1          2020-03-01 00:02:25     35.2323    123.23
  2          2020-03-06 04:27:22     45.2323    121.23
  3          2020-03-06 06:59:59     13.2323    127.23
```

This is what I am doing right now however it seems very inefficient way and prone to error.

```
lng_list = []
lat_list = []
for row in df_1.itertuples():
    created_time    = getattr(row, "created_time")
    user_id         = getattr(row, "user_id") 

    df = df_2.loc[(df_2["user_id"] == user_id) &
                  (df_2["updated_time"] >= created_time)].copy()    
    if len(df) != 0:
        row = df.iloc[0]

    else:
        last_df = df_2.loc[(df_2["user_id"] == user_id) &
                           (df_2["created_time"] <= created_time)].copy()

        if len(last_df) == 0:
            lng_list.append(np.nan)
            lat_list.append(np.nan)
        else:
            row = last_df.iloc[-1]


    lng_list.append(row["lng"])
    lat_list.append(row["lat"])

df_1["lng"] = lng_list
df_1["lat"] = lat_list
```

Then after creating lists I am going to insert into df_1 which doesn't seem like a good practice and is prone to error...

So my desired output would be:

```
user_id      created_time          lat         lng
  1          2020-03-01 00:00:25   35.2323   123.23  <- within 5min range
  2          2020-03-06 04:20:25   NaN        NaN   
  3          2020-03-06 07:00:15   13.2323    127.23
```

Comment: Could you please share an input/desired output for your problem ?

Comment: @isabella Sorry for confusion, I've added it hope this is for clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple `user_id` in both dataframes, then `merge` might be your best option:

```
new_df = (df_1.merge(df_2, on='user_id', how='right')
              .assign(time_diff=lambda x: x.created_time.sub(x.updated_at)
                                           .abs().lt(pd.to_timedelta(5, unit='min')),
                     )
         )
new_df.loc[~new_df['time_diff'], ['lat','lng']] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
   user_id        created_time          updated_at      lat     lng  time_diff
0        1 2020-03-01 00:00:25 2020-03-01 00:02:25  35.2323  123.23       True
1        2 2020-03-06 04:20:25 2020-03-06 04:27:22      NaN     NaN      False
2        3 2020-03-06 07:00:15 2020-03-06 06:59:59  13.2323  127.23       True
```

Note that this might not solve your problem because you would have multiple `updated_at` for each `create_time`.

Comment: Thanks. It gives me `InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` since I have multiple user_id?

Comment: Also doesn't it only add 5mins? I need both 5 min past and 5 min after

Comment: Yup they can have multiple.

Comment: And also, that gives you a sample for upper thresh. You can easily  make a lower thresh with the same idea.

Comment: If they have multiple, then how do you decide which creation date is used for which row? Or do df_1 and df_2 align row-by-row?

Comment: That is why I am adding time to it. for user1 he/she will be in dataframe multiple times with all different times.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following solution.

```
# Convert date column into datetime object 
df1['created_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['created_time'])
df2['updated_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['updated_at'])

# Create filters based on condition
user_id_condition = df1['user_id'] == df2['user_id'] 
n_min_before = df1['created_time'] - pd.to_timedelta(5, unit='min')
n_min_after = df1['created_time'] + pd.to_timedelta(5, unit='min')
time_condition = (df2['updated_at'] <= n_min_after) & (n_min_before <= df2['updated_at'])

# Apply filters and find intersection rows in df2
intersect_df2 = df2[user_id_condition & time_condition][['lat', 'lng', 'user_id']]

# Merge df1 with intersect_df2 (left merge preserves size of df1)
output_df = pd.merge(df1, intersect_df2, on='user_id', how='left')
```

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention there can be multiple user_id hence it is giving me `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

Comment: multiple user_id in df1, df2 or both?

Comment: both, I've fixed my question.

Comment: For which line the error occurs? Btw, I added previous time condiiton too

Comment: user_id_condition = df1['user_id'] == df2['user_id']  This line creates value error I've mentioned above.